# SDK location for android studio on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, android-studio, android-sdk

Hi I am having trouble finding the SDK location for android-studio. I installed it following this website - http://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/
However when I go to the SDK location in configuration page it is blank and I can't find the SDK location anywhere, it just says please choose a valid android SDK directory.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using locate to find a file in the "missing" directory:

```
locate "SDK Readme.txt"
```

should do it (don't forget the quotes, there's a space in the name"

Comment: Ok I will try that, just out of curiosity I found somewhere that I also have to download and install this -https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools is this the case, and if so where do I install it to.

Comment: Once you get the SDK running, you can download the tools from it, along with your selected android versions.

Answer (score 1):

just write this at your terminal prompt:

locate "SDK Readme.txt"

and follow the path returned