# Problem with Adroid SDK of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

While following [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu) and [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) to install **Android-studio** as a solution for [Android emulator independent of Virtual Box/VM-ware capability](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) there is a proble that the file we download from [Developer.Android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) as [sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip) does not contain the `add-ons` and `platforms` and I can find just the `tools` folder .
Below image is from [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) that shows the files used to be in downloading folder.
[image: missing files]

So when I try to run Android studio I get this message that No Android SDK is found.
[image: No Android SDK Found]

In next step installing/updating components, it says that Android SDK is installed.
[image: Can't check the SDK to download because it says it is installed]

Next step says that Android SDK is up to date but SDK tools directory is missing.
[image: SDK tools directory is missing]

And nothing works properly. ! Please specify a Android SDK Location.
[image: Please specify a Android SDK location.]

Trying [SDK location for android studio on ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549441/sdk-location-for-android-studio-on-ubuntu-14-10?rq=1)'s solution, I couldn't find any "SDK Readme.txt"

Comment: Specify the SDK location as `/home/casper/Downloads/android-sdk-linux`?

Comment: @AndroidDev that's the path of downloaded `/andorid-sdk-linux` which is from the 2 years old complete guide. It doesn't work because that folder doesn't contain the required SDK anymore.

Comment: Ok, so download the SDK again from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip)

Comment: there is only a folder named `tools` in `sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip` and Android Studio can not find any SDK in this folder

Answer (score 1):

The current direct link for SDK Tools package is (2018-12-31): https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip. But, as others have already said in other responses to similar questions on SO, the best way is to let Android Studio handle the installation, because it will install other useful apps, too (emulator, platform tools, etc). In my case, I wasn't connected to the internet when I first started Android Studio, so I got stuck at the same error. After removing the ~/.AndroidStudio3.2 folder and a ./studio.sh restart, it asked me to download all the necessary apps (note: the dowload has ~1GB!) and then Android Studio started flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, do **NOT** configure the **Automatic proxy configuration URL** (URL to .pac file), because this didn't worked for me.

Configure the proxy **manually**, this fixed it for me.