# Error about virtualbox-ext-pack when trying to install or uninstall any software

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox

Whenever I try to install anything I get this error (this error is when I try to install firefox)

```
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.0.40-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-ext-pack.postinst: 18: cd: can't cd to /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Whenever I try to unistall anything I get this error (this error I get when trying to remove virtualbox)

```
Removing virtualbox-ext-pack (5.0.40-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-ext-pack.prerm: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-ext-pack.prerm: vboxmanage: not found
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Earlier I had tried to install VMware but my laptop does not support required technology [and every attempt to get around it failed!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948754/problem-with-adroid-sdk-of-android-studio)

I tried to remove virtualbox with methods [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software) and this is the result:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 873830 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-ext-pack (5.0.40-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-ext-pack.prerm: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-ext-pack.prerm: vboxmanage: not found
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing virtualbox-qt (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-qt (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: virtualbox: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-5.0; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 5.0.40-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-5.0; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-5.0; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 5.0.40-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-5.0; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.0 is not i
Removing virtualbox (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing virtualbox, directory '/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While trying `sudo apt-upgrade` I got this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-ext-pack : Depends: virtualbox (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0~) or
                                virtualbox-5.0 but it is not installable
                       Depends: virtualbox (< 5.0.40-dfsg-z) or
                                virtualbox-5.0 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: 1. Did you install `virtualbox` before trying with virtualbox-ext-pack? 2. Please tell us about your computer (brand name and model).

Comment: @sudodus ; yes, I first installed virtualbox. I have Lenovo G550

Comment: 1. Is this link desrcibing your computer: [Lenovo G550 2958 - 15.6" - P T4200 - Vista Home Premium 64-bit - 4 GB RAM - 320 GB HDD Series](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-g550-2958-15-6-p-t4200-vista-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd-series/specs/)? 2. Did the problem start after you installed `virtualbox`? 3. Have you removed `vmware`? Can you install some other program, for example `htop`?

Comment: Not exactly, my computer is Lenovo G550 Model 20023. I didn't notify when exactly it started but befor installing virtual box I had not this problem for sure.I tried but I got the second error. No, I can't install any other program even firefox

Comment: How did you install vmware and virtualbox? From the Ubuntu repositories via `sudo apt install ...` or some other way? -- Whichever method you used, please try to remove them using the matching method to how you installed them.

Comment: I always install via sudo apt-get so I tried to remove or purge via sudo apt-get as you said but same error as "Unmet dependencies"

Answer (score 1):

Let us hope that one or more of the commands by @oldfred and some other experienced users in the following list can help you.

```
# Oldfred's command list for cleaning and repairing

#houseclean
sudo apt-get autoclean # only removes files that cannot be downloaded anymore (obsolete)
sudo apt-get clean

#refresh
sudo apt-get update #resync package index
sudo apt-get upgrade #newest versions of all packages, update must be run first

#would upgrade you to the latest kernel in the repositories
#dist-upgrade is also able to remove existing packages if required
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

# fix Broken packages -f 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a

# Remove lock
# If you are absolutely sure you do not have another upgrade process running.
# Locked dpkg - only if sure you are not running another update.

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a 

# added zika's tip for problems with hash sum mismatch

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

# added 2F4U's tips for Package Manager & Update Manager problems

Does executing these commands help?

cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update

This will rebuild the cache.
```

If it doesn't help, this forum thread has additional suggestions:

[GPG key error when attemting to download updates](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869890)

Comment: I tried it expect updating distribution  due to insufficient disk space. still the same error : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-ext-pack : Depends: virtualbox (< 5.0.40-dfsg-z) or
                                virtualbox-5.0 but it is not installable

Comment: Did you try to fix broken packages with these commands?  `sudo apt-get -f install` ; `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Yes, I tried. I think it might be because of using third-party dependencies

Comment: Which third-party dependencies?

Comment: Oops, sry, I mean "Third-party repositories"

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, still same error

Comment: Which third-party repositories?

Comment: In fact, I don't know, I was reading some article on net that was saying something about this. one other time I had problems to update, error was about because of third-party repository or third-party dependecies

Comment: Let us try this way: Check all your repositories (and list them). Maybe we can identify a repository and some program package from it, that might cause problems. *Let us invite other people, to help you with this task.* Please edit your original question to add a list of the repositories that you use.